# Inner div has unwanted space in relation to wrapper

Tags: html, margin, padding, space, multiple-columns

I can't find a solution to this..

I have three divs floating next to each other to create a 3-column lay-out within a wrapper div. For some reason the left one is 40px away from the wrapper's border.
Everything else works perfectly, just some unwanted space on the left.

This is my code..

html:

```
<div id="panelwrapper">
   <ul>
      <li>
         <div id="panel-left">
         </div>
      </li>

      <li>
         <div id="panel-mid">
         </div>
      </li>  

      <li>
         <div id="panel-right">
         </div>
      </li>                                    
   </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
#panelwrapper   {
    height: 398px;
    width: 1023px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    clear: both;
}

#panelwrapper ul li {
    display: inline;
}

#panel-left {
    width: 339px;
    height: 396px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
}

#panel-mid  {
    width: 339px;
    height: 396px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
}

#panel-right    {
    width: 339px;
    height: 396px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a CSS reset stylesheet?

If not, you'll need to set the UL's margin/padding to 0.

Comment: I'm not using a reset stylesheet. Unfortunately adjusting margin/padding doesn't work.

I'm using these divs inside Kwicks for jQuery, but I don't think that's interfering.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: I'm using the Kwicks js scripts. I have to admit I'm pretty new to this and there's some coding in the head section, others linked to a .js file. I don't really know how to properly input the data into JSFiddle tbh.

Comment: Tried to create a JSFiddle. Output isn't exactly the same since I don't think it's using the Kwicks-script, but my problem has a face now ;)
http://jsfiddle.net/z4Jsj/

Comment: I'm a bit busy right now, but nothing is jumping out at me... You may want to try moving those divs outside the ul.

Comment: So simple! Thanks man.

The UL was a solution to an earlier problem that's not an issue anymore :)